# re-revert error data with non-external function

Tags: solidity, contract-design

my question is how what if one of swaps in `doSwapChain` revert how i can re-revert that error(UniswapV2 error) with my error that have the index number of the swap and also the error that reverted(Uniswapv2). i read about `try-catch` but its for external functions. i could use `try-catch` inside `swapUniswapV2Protocol` when call `routerToBuy.swapExactTokensForTokens` but how i can get the same error that uniswapv2 throw?

```
function swapUniswapV2Protocol(
    address router,
    address tokenIn,
    address tokenOut,
    uint256 amountIn,
    uint256 amountOutMin,
    uint256 deadline
) private returns (uint256 amountOut) {
    IERC20 tIn20 = IERC20(tokenIn);
    require(tIn20.balanceOf(address(this)) >= amountIn, "No enough amount to swap");
    require(tIn20.approve(router, amountIn), "routerToBuy failed to approve");
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = tokenIn;
    path[1] = tokenOut;
    if (deadline == 0) {
        deadline = block.timestamp;
    }
    IUniswapV2Router02 routerToBuy = IUniswapV2Router02(router);
    uint256[] memory amounts = routerToBuy.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountIn,
        amountOutMin,
        path,
        address(this),
        deadline
    );
    // amounts[0] = Input token amount, amounts[1] = Output token amount
    return amounts[1];
}

function doSwapChain(OneSwapInfo[] memory swaps) private returns (uint256[] memory amountOut) {
    require(swaps.length > 0, "Empty swap chain");

    amountOut = new uint256[](swaps.length);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < swaps.length; i++) {
        OneSwapInfo memory curSwap = swaps[i];
        // What if one of swap reverted how i can report the index of failed swap
        amountOut[i] = swapUniswapV2Protocol(
            curSwap.Router,
            curSwap.TokenIn,
            curSwap.TokenOut,
            curSwap.AmountIn,
            curSwap.AmountOutMin,
            curSwap.Deadline
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catching the error like this:

```
    try routerToBuy.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountIn,
        amountOutMin,
        path,
        address(this),
        deadline
    ) returns (uint256[] memory amounts) {
        return amounts[1];
    } catch Error(string memory reason) {
        revert ErrorWithIndex(index, reason);
    }
```

where you can define the custom error `ErrorWithIndex` like this:

```
error ErrorWithIndex(uint256 index, string reason);
```

and you need to pass `index` in the `swapUniswapV2Protocol` function:

```
function swapUniswapV2Protocol(
    address router,
    address tokenIn,
    address tokenOut,
    uint256 amountIn,
    uint256 amountOutMin,
    uint256 deadline,
    uint256 index           // add this
) private returns (uint256 amountOut) {
```

```
        amountOut[i] = swapUniswapV2Protocol(
            curSwap.Router,
            curSwap.TokenIn,
            curSwap.TokenOut,
            curSwap.AmountIn,
            curSwap.AmountOutMin,
            curSwap.Deadline,
            i                // add this
        );
```

Comment: Thats good approach thanks.